# 3 Coloring a Baton of n Bands

Tags: combinatorics

Using, Burnside's Lemma, how many ways are there to $3$-color the $n$ bands of a baton if adjacent bands must be a different color?

Workings:

The first band has $3$ choices for color, the next bands has only $2$ choices since it can not be the same color as adjacent bands.

So $3 \times 2^{n-1}$ is the number of ways to chose these rings of a fixed baton.

If the baton revolves $180^o$ then

$3 \times 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$

So $N = \frac{1}{2} (3 \times 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}})$

I'm not sure if what I said is right. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You are very near. Maybe it helps when you look carefully at the cases $n=3$, $n=4$, and $n=5$. In this way you can avoid invoking the full "Polya theory".

Comment: If $n = 3$ the ways to colr the baton are $RBR, RBO, ROR, ROB, BRB, BRO, BOB, ORO, OBO$ these are 9. Using the formula I printed gives $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These  batons  represent  the  flip  permutation group  $F_n$  on  $n$
elements that contain two permutations. The cycle indices are

$$Z(F_n) = \frac{1}{2}(a_1^n + a_2^{n/2})$$

for $n$ even and

$$Z(F_n) = \frac{1}{2}(a_1^n + a_1 a_2^{(n-1)/2})$$

for $n$ odd.

In order  to apply  Burnside we  ask how many  colorings are  fixed by
these two permutations. This gives for the first case
$$\frac{1}{2}(3\times 2^{n-1} + 0)
= 3\times 2^{n-2}$$

when  $n$  even  and  $n\ge  2$,  because in  order  to  be  fixed  by
$a_2^{n/2}$ the  two middle  slots would have  to have the  same color
which is not admissible, and for the second case

$$\frac{1}{2}(3\times 2^{n-1} + 2\times 3\times 2^{(n-1)/2-1})
= 3\times 2^{n-2} + 3\times 2^{(n-1)/2-1}.$$

where $n\gt 1$.  There are three colorings when  $n=1$ and the formula
also applies here.

This gives the following sequence $\{A_n\}$:
$$3, 3, 9, 12, 30, 48, 108, 192, 408, 768, 1584, 3072,\ldots$$

Admittedly this problem  is *extremely simple* but since  there was no
OEIS entry for the sequence I  wrote a Maple program to compute it for
small $n$ by  total enumeration.  The program confirmed  the values of
the sequence. This is the Maple code.

```
A :=
proc(n)
    if type(n, even) then return 3*2^(n-2) fi;

    3*2^(n-2)+3*2^((n-1)/2-1);
end;

verif :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local ind, res, ent, digits, str1, str2, pos;

    res := {};

    for ind from 3^n to 2*3^n-1 do
        digits := convert(ind, base, 3);

        for pos to n-1 do
            if digits[pos] = digits[pos+1] then
                break;
            fi;
        od;

        if pos = n then
            str1 := [seq(digits[pos], pos=1..n)];
            str2 := [seq(digits[n+1-pos], pos=1..n)];

            res := {op(res), {str1, str2}};
        fi;
    od;

    nops(res);
end;
```

Comment: Alright, thanks I never used Maple before and as far as I'm aware my university has no courses that deals with Maple which is odd considering I am getting a Computational Math degree. I do intend on learning it though. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some colourings are invariant under reversal, so dividing by $2$ will under-count them.  This is where Burnside comes in.